# Using ArrayList in polymorphism

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, superclass

Hi everyone I need some explanations about "for each" which contains this code:

```
for(**Employee e**:hp.getStaff()) {
        
        if(e instanceof Secretary) {
            Secretary s = (Secretary)e;
            System.out.println("Type is: " + s.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and his index is: " + hp.getStaff().indexOf(e));
        }else if(e instanceof Manager) {
            Manager m = (Manager)e;
            System.out.println("Type is: " + m.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and his index is: " + hp.getStaff().indexOf(e));
        }else if(e instanceof Engineer) {
            Engineer en = (Engineer)e;
            System.out.println("Type is: " + en.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and his index is: " + hp.getStaff().indexOf(e));
        }else if(e instanceof Director) {
            Director d = (Director)e;
            System.out.println("Type is: " + d.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and his index is: " + hp.getStaff().indexOf(e));
        }
    }
```

So... **in bold we have "Employee e", what does it means?**
All classes (Secretary,Manager, Director, Engineer) extend Employee; a class Company contains the attribute *private ArrayList staff;* , and his constructor is:

```
public Company() {
    
    staff = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
}
```

Hope you can help me to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows an ArrayList of Employees where, when iterated over, checks the actual type of the object. One thing to understand us that each instance inside this collection is a subtype if Employee in some way.

The instanceof operater will determine the actual class that the instance belongs to. After making this check, it is then safe to down cast this instance from a reference if Employee to an instance if that subclass. Down casting can provide a me special benefits, mainly that it can be stored in a collection of a super type while still holding specific functionality of it's type.

Although this example does not necessary display any special functionality if the sub classes, the System.out's could easily be replaced with anything special that class has, thus providing an actual need for the down cast.

Imagine you wanted to fire an employee, but whoever you chose from the collection needed to be of higher ranking within the company. You can iterate over the list, check if the instance is of any applicable type, down cast it, then call some method like fireEmployee(Employee e) on that object (even though that method doesn't exist on employee's, it could on Director).

Inheritance in java allows us to store these objects as a common type, and treat them as themselves or parents to allow access to those bits if functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

`hp.getStaff()` is a method that returns a `staff` collection. In this case you have an `ArrayList` of `Employee`s. `Employee` is a parent class for `Secretary`, `Manager`, `Engineer` and `Director`. Your `staff` contains not abstract items (`Employee` objects), but real (`Manager`, `Engineer`, etc. objects).

So, inside a loop you iterate over the `staff` collection:

```
for (Employee e: hp.getStaff()) {
}
```

Then you check every new item, whether is it an instance of `Manager` or `Engineer` classes. If it is `Secretary`, for instance, you cast an item to `Secretary` class and get it's value: `hp.getStaff().indexOf(e)`.